# Global variant of Jeffreys Prior

Tags: bayesian, information-theory, inference

The Jeffreys prior can be viewed as a way to ensure that "accidental similarities" between nearby models in some hypothesis space do not produce commensurate "accidental biases" in inference/hypothesis testing processes. More specifically, the Jeffrey's prior uniformizes the prior distribution with respect to the Fisher information metric, which can be thought of as an infinitesimal variant of the traditional KL divergence (from information theory; recall that the KL divergence is not a true metric, because $d_{KL}(p_1,p_2) \neq d_{KL}(p_2, p_1)$ in general for arbitrary probability distributions $p_1$, $p_2$, but that when the asymmetry vanishes qualitatively faster than $d_{KL}(p,p+\delta p)$ does in the scaling limit, the Fisher information metric is in fact a bona fide metric.)

One possible shortcoming of the Jeffrey's prior is that while it can be used to eliminate/mitigate bias locally to some extent (when used/interpreted appropriately), it fails to do so for accidental 'global coincidences' in hypothesis space (e.g. if $p_{\omega}\approx p_{\omega'}$ for $\omega$ very very different from $\omega'$, the Jeffreys prior would fail to take this redundancy into account.) Is there a well-known/canonical "correction" to the Jeffreys prior that accounts for the possibility of "accidental symmetries" in hypothesis space?  (For example, could accidental duplicate models be thought of as "discrete" gauge symmetries?)  Obviously this question is complicated somewhat by the fact that in certain contexts, multiple distinct/independent possibilities must be considered that produce qualitatively similar outcomes, and those possibilities cannot be 'collapsed' into a single, monolithic 'effective possibility' (it's sort of the difference between considering the probability that a particular side effect is caused by any of a large number of active components, and the probability of accidentally saying 'yes' when asked for the millionth time if the side effect was caused by ingredient X.)